# Is it a way to publish latest and one before latest version of an app in App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

For safety reason we would like to offer to our customer to download the version before the latest one in App Store. Is it possible?

Comment: You could offer two versions of the app in the app store. I don't know what apple's policy might be.  But, its a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is call the Apple Developer Program Support number for your country and discuss the situation.

The direct link is: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

However, I have seen other developer take one of the following two approaches:

- You release the previous version of the app again for a limited time and make it very clear in the description that this is a limited release only for XYZ reasons and advise which users should and should not install this version. After the period is over, re-release the newer update.
- You release the newer version of the App using a different name, bundle ID etc. For example, if your older app is version 1.4.2, you rerelease that with an updated version (e.g. 1.4.4) and also re-release your 1.4.3 version as a totally new one as version 2.0. This is effectively a different app.

I've seen some big name apps used both approaches in the past, but of course Apple regularly changes its guidelines and this may or may not be possible.